# importing the request in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm creating a helper method in my code which I can use for authorizing users,

I am creating a function called `"usePermissions"` following the react way but on the back-end.

The `usePermissions()` will return true or false based on some x, y and z.

But this method depends on the request object,

so in order to make it work, I'll everywhere have to call
`usePermissions(req)`,
ex:

```js
import usePermissions from 'hooks/usePermissions'

usersRouter.delete('/users/:userId', async (req, res, next)=>{
  const { verify } = usePermissions(req)
  if(verify('deleteUsers')) await UserModel.delete(req.params.userId)
  // ...
})
```

Is there a way to package this `"usePermissions"` helper method with the request object?

I want it to automatically have the request object, I don't want to keep passing it as a variable,

how to make it have the request object without having to pass it as an argument to it, is it possible?

ex:

```js
import usePermissions from 'hooks/usePermissions'

usersRouter.delete('/users/:userId', async (req, res, next)=>{
  const { verify } = usePermissions() // <-- see, I want to not pass the req object
  if(verify('deleteUsers')) await UserModel.delete(req.params.userId)
  // ...
})
```

Comment: You can do it with middleware function, catch request object in between, set your helper into it with something like this `request.usePermissions = usePermissions` and then just call `next()` function and your next one will get your util with the request

Comment: have you looked at this https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html ?

Comment: @The_flash, yes of course, but I don't want a middleware. _I know the custom middlewares. I've thought about that, but I found that using a helper function is better for my case than using a middleware, because making it a middleware will either allow or forbid the user from accessing the entire route. Sometimes you'll want the user to be able to access the route, but with fewer permissions, like for example, allowing him only to delete the items he creates, but forbidding him from deleting the items that gets created by other users, and so on_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a middleware that will call `usePermissions` and append result to the Request object, so it will become available in all your handlers without explicitly calling it.

Your middleware code might look something like (read more about using [middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) in Express app)

```
export function getUsePermissions = (req, res, next) => {
  const { verify } = usePermissions(req);
  req['verify'] = verify

  // moving to the next middleware in chain, now Request object has a verify property
  return next()
}
```

and in your express app, add `getUsePermissions` middleware

```
express.use(getUsePermissions);
```

now you can use extract `usePermissions` from request object in your handlers:

```
usersRouter.delete('/users/:userId', async (req, res, next)=>{
  const { verify } = req['verify'];
  if(verify('deleteUsers')) await UserModel.delete(req.params.userId)
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Great, but I wish there was a way to use es imports for this, I don't think this is possible with express though

Comment: You don't need return for the next. Also, adding middleware with use will ask every request to check for permission and I am afraid user won't be able to even signup.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, It depends on where you call the `.use()` method

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to say, but you didn't mention that where to add it.

Comment: Comment is correct - the code above is just an example, of course you can define your middleware for specific routes only

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it as middleware and you will get a response, request and next object by default.

```
import usePermissions from 'hooks/usePermissions'

usersRouter.delete('/users/:userId', usePermissions , async (req, res, next)=>{
  if(verify('deleteUsers')) await UserModel.delete(req.params.userId)
  // ...
})
```

usePermissions Function will be like this:

```
const usePermissions = (request, response, next) => {

      const isPermitted = 'you logic';
      if (isPermitted) {
          next(); // this will automatically call the next middleware 
                  // in your case it will call the next callback in the userRouter
      } else {
         response.send('You don't have permission'); // just added a sample text for brevity
      }
      
}
```

You can read more about [middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) here.

Comment: Where does the "verify" come from?

Comment: I just copied your code, I thought you might be using another function as verify. You can remove that. The gist of the answer us how you can use the functions as middleware.

Comment: yeah, I know the custom middlewares. I've thought about that, but I found that using a helper function is better for my case than using a middleware, because making it a middleware will either allow or forbid the user from accessing the entire route. Sometimes you'll want the user to be able to access the route, but with fewer permissions, like for example, allowing him only to delete the items he creates, but forbidding him from deleting the items that gets created by other users, and so on,

Comment: I think the question you asked is to import the request object in the express and this is how you should do it. There could be more details added to question in order to get that sort of answer.

Comment: yes, Sorry for that 

Comment: No worries, here to help don't be sorry 